# Invalid File Extension while uploading files in CKFINDER with asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, ckeditor, fckeditor, ckfinder

I am using CKFinder 2.4.1.2663 and CKEditor 3.6.4.0 in my asp.net project. I am able to upload images but when I try to upload any files like doc, xls or pdf and **click on send it to the server** button, it shows this error: **invalid file extension.**

In my code behind i have written this:

```
protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
{
    CKFinder.FileBrowser _FileBrowser = new CKFinder.FileBrowser();
    _FileBrowser.BasePath = "/ckfinder/";
    _FileBrowser.SetupCKEditor(CKEditor1);
}
```

and in **Config.ascx** i have changed this code

```
public override bool CheckAuthentication()
{
    // WARNING : DO NOT simply return "true". By doing so, you are allowing
    // "anyone" to upload and list the files in your server. You must implement
    // some kind of session validation here. Even something very simple as...
    //
    //        return ( Session[ "IsAuthorized" ] != null && (bool)Session[ "IsAuthorized" ] == true );
    //
    // ... where Session[ "IsAuthorized" ] is set to "true" as soon as the
    // user logs on your system.
    return true;
}
```

I am using the control in my **aspx** like this

```
<CKEditor:CKEditorControl ID="CKEditor1" runat="server"></CKEditor:CKEditorControl>
```

I have to use CKFinder for images and any types of file extension. Where i am doing wrong?

Comment: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/45901/uploading-custom-files-using-ckfinder

Answer (score 0):

From the look of things i can see that the doc and xls file extensions where not allowed in your **Config.ascx**

By default, in the CKFINDER WINDOW the root folder is images and in the Config.ascx file, these file extensions (**doc,xls**) were not included in the ResourceType for the images folder.

so for you to get rid of this **ERROR**, Open the Config.ascx file and add the extensions (doc,xls) you want to the baseUrl "images", something like this and add

'allowedExtensions' => 'bmp,gif,jpeg,jpg,png,doc,xls

Note: Dont change anything just add the extensions separated by commas.

I know this will solve your problem, because it was an issue for me and i solved it doing it this way.But if you dont mind you can paste the complete config.ascx file and i do the direct update and you copy and paste it on your system and run it.